# Data structure to hold the data into the map into key value pairs

Tags: java

I am basically trying to create the data structre

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>
```

I have a map as shown below in which there is a key and values are of type `List`:

```
 Map<String, List<String> newdatamap = new HashMap<>();
    map.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
    map.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"))
```

I'd like to add another map over the previous map, such that there is a key and its value will be the above map. Is this the correct data structure, and how do we implement it?

I want something like this shown below

```
Key         Value

B1          payerName  ----> "wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"
            fixedRate ----->"dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"



B2          payerName  ----> "SSSwpn", "wpfSSSnb", "GGGdgeft", "xbtYYYYhy"
            fixedRate ----->"WWdd", "wTTYw", "YYYYtrrty", "IIIhttyure"
```

As shown above, only a new key has been introduced to the map, and its value is the previous map. So please advise how to create such map

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>.
```

Well I have tried through Google guava library I have shown below but I want to achieve same through java itself. Please advise how can i achieve the same through java

```
final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
values.put("B1", "payerName", Lists.newArrayList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
System.out.println(values.get("B1", "payerName")); // prints the list
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but from your example it seems you want to keep the relationship between the pairs of payerName and fixedRate, i.e. you want to stress that "wpn" is associated to "dd" and "wpfnb" to "ww". If that's the case, you are better off to put both values in a custom class (class info{String payerName, String fixedRate}) and have your map have values of that type (Map<String, List<Info>>). If I'm off, ignore this :)

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia Thanks a lot just a small request small piece of request can you please code a little that will help to grasp completely and clearly Thanks in advacne

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> map = new HashMap<> ();
map.put("B1", newdatamap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Few more details to the answer of assylias

```
    Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> ultimateMap = new HashMap<String,Map<String, List<String>>> ();

    Map<String, List<String>> map1 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map1.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
    map1.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"));

    Map<String, List<String>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    map2.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("SSSwpn", "wpfSSSnb", "GGGdgeft", "xbtYYYYhy"));
    map2.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("WWdd", "wTTYw", "YYYYtrrty", "IIIhttyure"));

    ultimateMap.put("B1", map1);
    ultimateMap.put("B2", map2);
```

I could not add it as a comment to the previous answer (too long). So added as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's beyond the scope of the question, but as OP asked me in the comment I'm answering here:

```
class Info {
  public final String payerName;
  public final String fixedrate;

  public Info(String pn, String fr) {
    payerName = pn;
    fixedRate = fr;
  }
}

[...]

Collection<Info> myInfo = new LinkedList<>();
myInfo.add(new Info("wpn", "dd"));
myInfo.add(new Info("wpfnb", "ww"));
myInfo.add(new Info("dgeft", "trrty"));
myInfo.add(new Info("xbthy", "httyure"));
Map<String, Collection<Info>> myData = new HashMap<>();
myData.put("B1", myInfo);
```